# Deny certain URLs in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I have the following code in my Scrapy project:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="/uniprot/[OPQ][0-9][A-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]|[A-NR-Z][0-9]([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]){1,2}"),
        callback="parsethings", follow=False),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_domains=["help", "category", "citations", "taxonomy","diseases", "locations", "docs", "uniref", "proteomes"])),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_domains=[".fasta","?version","?query","?"])),
]
```

I'm trying to scrape uniprot (www.uniprot.org) to get gene/protein names and lengths.

The first and last rules work to block the 10,000 copies of a gene page that have ".fasta" or a version revision number, however, I can't seem to get scrapy to block URLs under "/help", "/category", etc.

Basically, I only want to scrape URLs under uniprot.org/uniprot. If I set my allowed_domains to "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", then the spider actually blocks "www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q6GZX3" and then dies.

How can I get scrapy to only crawl URLs in the /uniprot subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Combine the second and the third rule into a single one:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="/uniprot/[OPQ][0-9][A-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]|[A-NR-Z][0-9]([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]){1,2}"),
        callback="parsethings", follow=False),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_domains=["help", "category", "citations", "taxonomy","diseases", "locations", "docs", "uniref", "proteomes", ".fasta", "?version", "?query", "?"])),
]
```

Comment: Scrapy still crawls these URLs with this rule, though it crawls them much faster than the last time I ran the spider.

Comment: Are you saying that the list in `deny_domains` are all subdomains of the uniprot domain? For example, `help.uniprot.com`, `category.uniprot.com`, `citations.uniprot.com` are all subdomains? Maybe I am misunderstanding the `deny_domains` class but doesn't that require a single or list of domains, not paths?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but shouldn't you use a single rule for this:

```
rules = [
     Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="/uniprot/[OPQ][0-9][A-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]|[A-NR-Z][0-9]([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]){1,2}", deny_domains=["help", "category", "citations", "taxonomy","diseases", "locations", "docs", "uniref", "proteomes", ".fasta", "?version", "?query", "?"]),
    callback="parsethings")
]
```

Edit: removed duplicate bracket + `follow=false`

Comment: Besides it would crawl nothing since it would not follow any link.

Comment: @crashfocus hm, I've tested it - got nothing crawled. Which URL are you starting with?

Comment: @alecxe http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot

Unfortunately, it only crawls a few of the genes before exiting (but it does crawl them!)

Comment: @alecxe The updated code *does* block unwanted URLs, but it only scrapes something like 25 of the genes before exiting.

Comment: Isn't that because those are the only genes linked from the page at uniprot.org/uniprot/ ?

Comment: Ah. How can I then get the script to go to EVERY gene page, save for implementing some messed up paging function?

Comment: Well, If the uniprot site has a page that lists all of the genes, then you could start scraping from there. Although, maybe you'd be better downloading all the data (probably as text or tab separated) and parsing that to get the values that you want?

Comment: I actually did try to work with their XML download, however I don't have enough time to learn lxml to the degree I need to.

Comment: Would removing ``?query`` from the deny domains help, that could be preventing the spider from getting different pages of results. (Although I don't know if they'd match the regexp anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Use `deny` instead of `deny_domains`.